# export 10 first records from SPSSto text file

Tags: statistics, spss

I hope you are having a good day. I need your help! I have recently worked on IBM SPSS v23 program, and everything was going fine, until I needed to export JUST 10 first records from SPSS to a text file. I tried 'Save as', but it won't give me the chance to export just 10 first records to a text file.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With "10 first records" do you mean the first 10 cases (lines) of the datasheet?

Comment: It depends on how exactly you are exporting the records, but for many procedures you can use `TEMPORARY.` and then `SELECT IF $casenum <= 10.` before the save procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this.

do if $casenum <= 10.
xsave outfile="c:/temp/firstten.sav".
end if.